# OGRE1.9 build error on OSX

Tags: macos, cmake, makefile, homebrew, ogre

I am trying to install ogre v1.9 using homebrew. `brew install ogre --HEAD`
At some point I get the following errors:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN4Ogre18ControllerFunctionIfE16getAdjustedInputEf in:
CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreAlignedAllocator.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreAnimation.cpp.o

duplicate symbol __ZN4Ogre18ControllerFunctionIdE16getAdjustedInputEd in:
CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreAlignedAllocator.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/src/OgreAnimation.cpp.o
...
ld: 564 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [lib/macosx/Ogre.framework/Versions/1.9.0/Ogre] Error 1
make[1]: *** [OgreMain/CMakeFiles/OgreMain.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
==> Formula
Tap: osrf/homebrew-simulation
Path: /usr/local/Library/Taps/osrf/homebrew-simulation/ogre.rb
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
HEAD: 01dd3e19f8e600c3f44a3b140103f330aa32447c
Last commit: 3 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: 8-core 64-bit haswell
OS X: 10.10.2-x86_64
Xcode: N/A
CLT: 6.2.0.0.1.1424975374
Clang: 6.0 build 600
X11: 2.7.7 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 2.0.0-p481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
Java: N/A
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
MAKEFLAGS: -j8
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/opt/X11/include:/opt/X11/include/freetype2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/X11/lib:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libzzip/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.10:/opt/X11/lib/pk    gconfig:/opt/X11/share/pkgconfig
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal:/opt/X11/share/aclocal
PATH:/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/local/opt/cmake/bin:/usr/local/opt/doxygen/bin:/usr/local/opt/libpng/bin:/usr/local/opt/freetype/bin:/usr/local/opt/libzzip/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Error: ogre HEAD did not build
```

The errors are so many and all in `OgreAlignedAllocator.cpp.o`. I think there is something defined twice. I tried to uninstall all OGRE dependencies and reinstall them again, but I still get the same error.

Any suggestion how can I solve or debug this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok! It was a mess in the last commit, I checked out a previous revision and it works.